# Чтение массива из файла (java)

Tags: java, массивы, файлы

Нужно прочитать двумерный массив из файла (записан в бинарном виде), код функции записи нашел на одном из форумов, но тема создавалась давно и никто пока не ответил. Помогите написать функцию чтения при условии что переменная this.Array обьявленая в классе.

```
public boolean Save(String path) {
    try {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        for (byte i=0; i<this.Array.length;i++) {
            for (byte j=0;j<this.Array[0].length;j++) {
                out.writeInt(this.Array[i][j]);
            }
        }

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;        
    }
}
```

Comment: что за недописанный кусок кода?

Comment: В чем конкретно у вас проблема при чтении массива? Что именно не получается? Не получается считывать именно двумерный массив? Или не знаете как осуществлять чтение из бинарных файлов? И допишите код, а то у вас обрывок получился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример кода для чтения из бинарного файла в матрицу:

```
int lineCount = 0;
while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) 
         matrix[lineCount][i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]);

    lineCount++;
}
```

Источник: [**enSO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045266/reading-contents-of-a-file-into-a-2d-array).

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь, сложив все ответы получилось вот это:

```
class Map {
    private int Array[][];
    ...
    public boolean Save(String path) {
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));

            out.writeInt(this.Array.length);
            out.writeInt(this.Array[0].length);

            for (byte i=0; i<this.Array.length;i++) {
                for (byte j=0;j<this.Array[0].length;j++) {
                    out.writeInt(this.Array[i][j]);
                }
            }

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;        
        }
    }
    public boolean Read(String path) {
        try {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));

            this.Array = new int[in.readInt()][in.readInt()];
            for (int[] args : this.Array) {
                for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
                    args[j] = in.readInt();
                }
            }

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Markdown не понимает теги `<pre>` и `<code>`, пользуйтесь отступом в четыре пробела (выделите весь свой блок кода и нажмите кнопку `{}` в редакторе, чтобы добавить отступы). Вы так же можете править свои ответы и вопросы, а не создавать новые без необходимости.